# Get neighbouring key/value pairs in tree map for given key

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, treemap

I'm using a tree map with data types Map < String, String > to store dates with its corresponding data. I want to be able to find out what the previous or next key are from a specified key. How can I get the neighboring key's from a specified key? I considered iterating through my Treemap but that is not very efficient.

Comment: What do you really mean by a neighboring key?  The Map data structure in Java does not maintain any order so the concept of neighboring has to be an external concept.

Comment: I had the impression that Treemap tracks the insert order. When I iterate through my Treemap it does so in the order of insertion.

Comment: A *TreeMap* is used for *sorting*. If you need to maintain order use a *LinkedHashMap*.

Comment: Sorry I actually used TreeMap for sorting purposes.

Comment: Not sure what you are getting at. If you want to iterate forwards and backwards use a *List*, which has `listIterator()` which allows you to move in both ways.

Comment: I re-worded my question to be a bit more clear. "Traverse" was probably the wrong word to use in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a given key, you can use the `higherKey(key)` and `lowerKey(key)` method, respectively.

There also are the corresponding `xxxEntry()` variants.